# How to redirect to another page after logon in mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm having a problem trying to redirect to another page after logging in successfully in my MVC4 project. I'm modified the MVC4 template so that it display logon username and password textbox on the main page rather than redirecting to another logon page. Once I login successfully

After logging in successfully, I want to redirect to another page but I'm having 2 problems depending on the method I choose.

1. Problem 1: It displays my page i.e. a page containing a grid with data, as part of my header on the main page.
2. Problem 2: It processes the page containing the grid with data but then it throws an error that my model is invalid as it is expecting a logon model rather than griddata model.

Both are obviously behaving incorrectly. Once I log in successfuly, I want to display the username on the top right of my main page, which means I do need to use the logon model, but I want my main section to display the grid from the other page so I need the griddata model, but I can't quite see how to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: When you redirect to an Action you can pass in a different model at that time as well. This is the third parameter in redirect/redirect to action method. About your problem 1, you should use a partial view where you can check if user is logged in or not via Context.

Comment: Adding some of the relevant code to your question would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

This is a multi-part answer, but what you need to do is:

1. On your login page, have a form which points to your login controller
2. In your account controller, handle the login action
3. In your layout page, you can reference the current logged in user like this

Examples follow:

1) Your login page

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Logon", "Account")) {
    @Html.TextBox("username")
    @Html.Password("password")
}
```

2)Your login/account controller

```
public class AccountController : Controller {
    public ActionResult Logon(string username, string password) {
          // login logic here

          // save the username
          Session["Username"] = username;

          // Or you can reference user the user identity
          Session["Username"] = User.Identity.Name;

          // Redirect somewhere when you're done
          return Redirect("LoggedInPage", "Home");
    }
}
```

3) In your _Layout header

```
@if(HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
   @Session["Username"]
   // or
   @HttpContext.User.Identity.Name
} else {
   <div>You should log in!</div>
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I've actually figured out what my problem was! What you have above is correct but the code I have doesn't actually use session which I prefer, but my problem was caused because I had a model defined in _loginPartial.hmt, which is where the code you mentioned in your part 3) is. Once I removed that, all worked as expected.